# Вывод связанных данных в symfony

Tags: php, symfony, php7, twig

Есть сущности категории(category), подкатегории(subcategory),
 товары(product).

Как можно вывести в Twig, в категориях подкатегории(render *.twig array('category' => $category)), (связь many to one), при выводе в контроллере категорий пр.(category.subcategory.name) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, для таких отношений существуют рекурсивный вывод в twig.

https://gist.github.com/tentacode/3892186

Если уровень вложенности известен, то лучше и проще сделать, через индексы в массиве.(То есть если есть категория и подкатегория, то проще пронумеровать подкатегорию)